# What is the "Control bar" checkbox on Experience Editor "View" tab supposed to do?

Tags: experience-editor

Today a content editor asked me what the "Control bar" checkbox on the Experience Editor "View" tab is supposed to do - and I did not know. In our instance, clicking the checkbox doesn't seem to do/change anything. I haven't been able to find documentation that tells me what the expected behavior is for this checkbox so we can further troubleshoot our instance. Does anyone have any info or have you experienced this same issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont you mean "controls"? see here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/content_authoring/the_editing_tools/the_experience_editor/the_experience_editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It changes how personalization of the component info is displayed in Experience Editor mode:

[image]

Uncheck it to hide the second bar which shows names of the conditions.

It may have also have similar impact on showing A/B tests in Experience Editor, but I'm not 100% sure now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Marek! Doesn't seem intuitive so I never would have guessed that! Much appreciate your help.